# System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException

Tags: wcf-binding

I have  wcf service which is deployed on Windows server 2003 with service pack2. my wcf services has been working since one year. but in recent days ,it is throwing the bellow exception. I looked around a ton and I can’t find anything. Everybody suggesting to install the WCF non-HTTP activation components. I am using IIS6,so I coud not find the non-HTTP activation on my server. My worries are that how this was working before.

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type
>   of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder,
>   be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented
>   properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:
>   '<HTML><HEAD><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml"
>   href="http://server.edu/mysign/Services/mysign.svc?disco....etc

Answer (score 0):

Below points may be helpful-
1. If you're hosting on IIS, you'll want to remove the  section from the WCF service's web.config file.
2. You can turn on WCF tracing at service side and client-side to see whether it can capture more detailed error information at underlying channel level.
3. May be you are getting error page html in response.
 http://www.vistax64.com/indigo/468-content-type-text-html-response-message-does-not-match-content-type-binding-text-xml-charset-utf-8-a.html